# How to find out if gke cluster has autoupgrade set

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, gcloud

As google states:

> In November 2019, node auto-upgrade will be enabled by default for newly created clusters and node pools. To disable it, use the `--no-enable-autoupgrade` flag

How can I check if an already existing cluster (or node-pool) has this currently activated?

---

Edit: As Adebisi states it can be found using:
`gcloud container clusters describe [cluster]` or
`gcloud container node-pools describe [node-pool] --cluster=[cluster]`

However the result will only contain the entry `management.autoUpgrade` if it is actually set to `true`. An alternative is using the google console web UI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/node-auto-upgrades) provides the steps to check if autoupgrade is enabled.

Comment: This just explains how to activate/deactivate it. It does explain how to retrieve the current setting.

Comment: You can use the gcloud container clusters describe [Describe](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/container/clusters/describe) to see the current status. You would look for 'autoupgrade' and see it stated 'true'

Comment: I really can't find it in there.

Comment: Under nodePools you would see management and then autoUpgrade

Comment: Ok it turns out that I only see that entry if it is actually set to `true` using `gcloud container clusters describe [cluster]`